# How to add pagination to a long list using React MaterialUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I am using react + materialUI for implementing a list and filter functionality. The list is expected to be populated from an Http request and can have large number of list items. So for this reason, I was looking into pagination in MaterialUI documentation but no clear implementation is there. I want to provide my list and hope the pagination component to break the data and show over multiple pages.

This is the link to materialUI component: https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/

Any help on how to proceed with this?

[Picture of the List view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUKbE.png)

**Edit**: I want to implement list item as a clickable component so that on click it redirects to the a list item specific dashboard.

**Update**: I've implemented it using the material-ui pagination component. Works fine!

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g0xo5?file=/demo.js

Comment: Its like a table or list view?

Comment: Its a List. I am getting an array in response and I am looping over it to generate <ListItem>s. I'm using material components.

Comment: I think you should decide how many item should be showed on 1 page and store a page number in your state, then show items that should show in that page. Like `yourItemList.subarray(((pageNumber - 1)*(numberOfItemsForPage)), ((pageNumber)*(numberOfItemsForPage)))`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would be doing, but I think angular material has a paginator component and I thought that must be the case with react material too and I'm missing something here.

Comment: Thanks for the code sandbox !

Comment: Is there a reason why the pagination numbers only appear on the first render of a page, and then disappear after the following renders? I'm specifically speaking about the numbers used for page navigation. I used your sandbox code by the way for this problem to appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should decide how many item should be showed on 1 page and store a page number in your state, then show items that should show in that page. Like `yourItemList.subarray(((pageNumber - 1)*(numberOfItemsForPage)), ((pageNumber)*(numberOfItemsForPage) - 1))`
You can combine this with material ui pagination, should work fine!

Answer (score 2):

I recently dealt with this issue with the following snippet (consider that my example required handling a complex object):

```
<Pagination count={data.sub.length%10===0 ? data.sub.length/10 : data.sub.length/10 +1} page={page} onChange={(event,val)=> setPage(val)}  />
```

For my example I wanted 10 items rendered per page (hence the division by 10) and I calculated whether there would be trailing elements that should be rendered using the modulo and ternary operators. Following this, presenting a reference to the current page and hook to change the current page will achieve the desired result. Remember that what is **most relevant** is the **amount of elements rendered at each page on the DOM**.